# Elasticseach, ignore field

Tags: elasticsearch

Ok so I have data in my document something to the following:

```
 "validanswers": {
    "10": "Option 10",
    "11": "Option 11",
    "12": "Option 12",
    "90": "Option 90",
    "98": "Option 98",
    "99": "Option 99",
    "01": "Option 01",
    "07": "Option 07",
    "07.1": "Option 07.1",
    "03": "Option 03",
    "12.1": "Option 12.1",
    "05": "Option 05",
    "02.4": "Option 02.4",
    "07.2": "Option 07.2",
    "06": "Option 06",
    "12.2": "Option 12.2",
    "04": "Option 04",
    "02.2": "Option 02.2",
    "02.1": "Option 02.1",
    "12.3": "Option 12.3",
    "02.3": "Option 02.3",
    "12.99": "Option 12.99",
    "04.1": "Option 04.1",
    "02": "Option 02",
    "12.4": "Option 12.4",
    "09": "Option 09",
    "08": "Option 08"
  },
```

What I would like to do, directly from elasticsearch as the document is being indexed is to completely ignore the entire structure of 'validanswers'. I don't need the data and I am working on reindexing some older data so we can upgrade to Elasticsearch 2.3.1, and it doesn't like the dots in the field names (for obvious reasons).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by specifying the [enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) mapping parameter to `false`.

**Example:**

```
PUT test
PUT test/test/_mapping
{
    "test" : {
        "properties": {
            "validanswers" : {
                "enabled" : false
            }
        }
    }
}
put test/test/1
{ 
    "validanswers": {
    "10": "Option 10",
    "11": "Option 11",
    "12": "Option 12",
    "90": "Option 90",
    "98": "Option 98",
    "99": "Option 99",
    "01": "Option 01",
    "07": "Option 07",
    "07.1": "Option 07.1",
    "03": "Option 03",
    "12.1": "Option 12.1",
    "05": "Option 05",
    "02.4": "Option 02.4",
    "07.2": "Option 07.2",
    "06": "Option 06",
    "12.2": "Option 12.2",
    "04": "Option 04",
    "02.2": "Option 02.2",
    "02.1": "Option 02.1",
    "12.3": "Option 12.3",
    "02.3": "Option 02.3",
    "12.99": "Option 12.99",
    "04.1": "Option 04.1",
    "02": "Option 02",
    "12.4": "Option 12.4",
    "09": "Option 09",
    "08": "Option 08"
    }
}

GET test/_search
```

**Results:**

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "validanswers": {
                  "10": "Option 10",
                  "11": "Option 11",
                  "12": "Option 12",
                  "90": "Option 90",
                  "98": "Option 98",
                  "99": "Option 99",
                  "01": "Option 01",
                  "07": "Option 07",
                  "07.1": "Option 07.1",
                  "03": "Option 03",
                  "12.1": "Option 12.1",
                  "05": "Option 05",
                  "02.4": "Option 02.4",
                  "07.2": "Option 07.2",
                  "06": "Option 06",
                  "12.2": "Option 12.2",
                  "04": "Option 04",
                  "02.2": "Option 02.2",
                  "02.1": "Option 02.1",
                  "12.3": "Option 12.3",
                  "02.3": "Option 02.3",
                  "12.99": "Option 12.99",
                  "04.1": "Option 04.1",
                  "02": "Option 02",
                  "12.4": "Option 12.4",
                  "09": "Option 09",
                  "08": "Option 08"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
```